# How to substitute values in the URL

Tags: bash, shell

I have a POST request URL using which I want to trigger it multiple machine. But substitution of `$SERVER` and `$PORT` not working.
Please help.

```
SERVER='x.y.z.p'
PORT='1234'

API='http://"$SERVER":"$PORT"/Service/'
echo $API
```

Comment: c.f. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for a detailed breakdown of how various types of quotes work in Bash.

Answer (score 2):

Try `API='http://'$SERVER':'$PORT'/Service/'`

or `API="http://$SERVER:$PORT/Service/"`

and put the echo command the line under...

Comment: It seems to be single-quote issue.Thanks for the help.

Comment: The first isn't ideal; it leaves the parameter expansion unquoted, which is OK *here*, where you have control over the values assigned to the parameters.